# Split cells value in multiple rows without copying the data from another cells

Tags: excel, vba

I've numbers in cells E4 as (54,68,78) and in E5 as(88,98)

I need those to get split in below format

E4: 54
E5: 68
E6: 78
E7: 88
E8: 98

But the main thing is only the E column value should be split with leaving blanks in Column A, B, C, D, F, G....

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please include your attempt (assuming you know about `Split`), no matter how poor. FYI: This is easily done through PowerQuery if you want to avoid `VBA`

Comment: No I haven't done

Comment: Have a look at [ask] a question with a [mcve] then. Make it clear what exactly it is you are trying and **include** your own attempt as this isn't a free coding website. I have voted to close for now as no attempt is made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Sub test()

    Dim str1 As String, str2 As String, strFull As String
    Dim arr As Variant

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        str1 = .Range("E4").Value
        str2 = .Range("E5").Value
        strFull = str1 & "," & str2

        arr = Split(strFull, ",")

        .Range("E4:E5").Clear

        .Range("E4").Resize(UBound(arr) + 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arr)

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: @SMACreations if the answer fits your needs vote it to help others with the same quetion.

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, there will be data in Column A, B, C, D and even F there line should get add and the data to be split.  And the data will not be only in E4 and E5 it'll be going continuously based on the spreadsheet